# Add Text on Product Image

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, frontend, product-view

We want to add Text on Product Image through frontend.

Is we need to use any  frontend libraries or is it possible only by **imagemagick or gdlibrary**.?

once we add text on image , we need to save that image in backend [order view page ]

is dislaying **WYSIWYG** Editor on product view page will work ?

There is no help i didt got when i googled it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fulfill your requirement, some extensions are available. Check this link : 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-personalization.html
https://www.gomage.com/gomage-product-designer.html